# Main page data is resetting automatically Flutter after user come back to second page to first page

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm stuck with one issue where once I click on the upload image button it will take me to the next page wherein upload image class I will choose the images from the camera or Gallery and I will click on done. In the done button I have written navigation. pop(context) to the first page but when I come back all the text field data is cleared whatever I have entered and again I need to enter it back which is quite frustrating all the time...PLease help me to solve the issue or show the way how to save the data?

```
    import '../blocs/addtrip_bloc.dart';
    import '../widgets/customtextformfield.dart';
    import 'CameraWidgetState.dart';
    
    class DataInfoPage extends StatefulWidget {
      const DataInfoPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
    }
    
    class _MyHomePageState extends State<DataInfoPage> {
      _DataInfoPageState createState() => _DataInfoPageState();
      String date = "";
    
      final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
      User? user;
      var name = '';
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        initUser();
        savedata();
      }
    
      initUser() async {
        user = (await _auth.currentUser!);
        name = user!.displayName!;
        setState(() {});
      }
    
      void savedata() {
        final absavedata = context.read<AddTripBloc>();
      }
    
      final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
    
      DateTime selectedDate = DateTime.now();
      TextEditingController tripname = new TextEditingController();
      TextEditingController sdate = new TextEditingController();
             
      DateTimeRange? _selectedDateRange;
    
      String _displayText(String begin, DateTime? date) {
        if (date != null) {
          return '$begin Date: ${date.toString().split(' ')[0]}';
        } else {
          return 'Press the button to show the picker';
        }
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
            body: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Form(
                key: _formKey,
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "Please enter trip details ",
                      style: const TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 25,
                          color: Colors.black),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 0),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            customfields(
                                hintValue: ' Enter Trip Name',
                                labeltxt: 'Trip Name *',
                                keyboardtype: TextInputType.text,
                                text: tripname),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 20,
                            ),
                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: [
                                FloatingActionButton(
                                    onPressed: _show,
                                    child: const Icon(Icons.date_range),
                                    shape: BeveledRectangleBorder(
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5))),
                                Column(
                                  children: [
                                    Text(
                                      _displayText(
                                          'Start', _selectedDateRange?.start),
                                      style: const TextStyle(
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                          fontSize: 15,
                                          color: Colors.black),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height: 20,
                                    ),
                                   
                            ElevatedButton(
                              onPressed: () async {
                                await Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => CameraWidget()));
                                // Navigator.push(
                                //     context,
                                //     MaterialPageRoute(
                                //         builder: (context) => CameraWidget()));
                              },
                              child: const Text("Upload Images of Trip *"),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 35,
                            ),
                            
                          ],
                        )),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ));
      }
    
      void _show() async {
        final DateTimeRange? result = await showDateRangePicker(
          context: context,
          firstDate: DateTime(2022, 1, 1),
          lastDate: DateTime(2030, 12, 31),
          currentDate: DateTime.now(),
          saveText: 'Done.',
        );
    
        if (result != null) {
          // Rebuild the UI
          print(result.start.toString());
          setState(() {
            _selectedDateRange = result;
          });
        }
      }
    }


Custom Flied Code
class customfields extends StatelessWidget {
  customfields(
      {required this.hintValue,
      this.labeltxt = "",
      required this.keyboardtype,
      this.maxvalue = 1,
      required this.text});
  String hintValue;
  String labeltxt;
  int maxvalue;
  TextInputType keyboardtype;

  TextEditingController text;
  bool _validate = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          TextFormField(
            controller: text,
            cursorColor: Colors.black,
            //textAlign: TextAlign.left,
            // autocorrect: true,
            // textInputAction: TextInputAction.go,
            // maxLines: maxvalue,
            // autofocus: true,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
            inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
              FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                  RegExp('[a-z A-Z 0-9 #?!@%^&* ? @ ^_ . : ! | "" \'-]')),
            ],
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: new UnderlineInputBorder(
                  // borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                  // borderSide: new BorderSide(),
                  ),
              hintText: hintValue,
              labelText: labeltxt,
              errorText: _validate ? 'Value Can\'t Be Empty' : null,

              //prefixIcon: Icon(Icons),
              //suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.currency_bitcoin)
            ),
            keyboardType: keyboardtype,
            validator: (value) {
              if (value!.isEmpty) {
                return "Value Can't be empty.";
              }
              return null;
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: add code for this widget customfields

Comment: Updated the code with customfields

Comment: Please help me with the issue

Comment: try making your customfields class final eg `final  TextEditingController text;`

Comment: Tried it but no changes..